# Issue on building .bff package in AIX 7.1

Tags: makefile, aix

While I am trying to create AIX package (.bff) I am getting following error.

> bash-4.2# make package

```
    cd buildroot; makebff /usr/bin/sh: makebff:  not found make: The error code from the last command is 127.
```

Stop.

I believe some environmental path reference are broken. Could some one please help

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem: `make package` gave me `make: *** No rule to make target 'package'.`

Comment: Hi Lorinczy.. I got the issue.. there was an issue issue with dependency package (IHS.makebff) I cloud able to build the .bff package now. However after building the package I tried to install the package using "intallp" I am getting an error saying ---

 """Completed postinstall
sysck: 3001-018 An error was encountered reading the input file.""""

few files are not able to readable.. Could you please understand me the issue.